# C++ Builder 6 Different Popup menu on Items and Subitems of a TreeView and No Popup on empty area

Tags: popup, treeview, c++builder, c++builder-6

I want to have different popup menu on Items and SubItems and NO Popup menu on empty area of a TTreeView is that possible ?

I want something like the pictures bellow

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do that.

1. Create 2 separate `TPopupMenu` objects with the desired menu items, do not assign either one of them to the TreeView's `PopupMenu` property, and then use the TreeView's `OnContextMenu` event to call the `Popup()` method of whichever `TPopupMenu` you need based on which node the user is clicking on.
2. Create 1 `TPopupMenu` object and put both menu items in it, and assign it to the TreeView's `PopupMenu` property, then use the `TPopupMenu.OnPopup` event to show/hide the menu items based on which node the user is clicking on.

In either case, you can use the `TTreeView.GetNodeAt()` method to determine which node is located at the coordinates of a mouse click, if any.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remy, and Thanks for GetHitTestInfoAt() Method I didn't know it. but GetHitTestInfoAt supports only the htOnItem Hit Test, how can determine the subitem ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `GetNodeAt()`, although `GetHitTestInfoAt()` can still be useful at times.

Comment: Yes GetNodeAt() because returns TTreeNode and with TreeNode I can get the Text or Index of items... Thanks Remy!